# Design for User hierarchy in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, authorization, hierarchy

I have an application that requires authentication, and have a User model. There are 4 levels of authorisation with the following rules:

1. Level 1 users can create/edit/delete all level 2,3 and 4 users.
2. Level 2 users can create level 3 and 4 users, and edit only those users they own.
3. Levels 3 and 4 have no authorisation to create/edit/delete users.
4. UPDATE: Level 3 and 4 users could have multiple level 2 parent users.

In addition to this, I want all users to be able to login through a single interface.

Are there any patterns for dealing with such a hierarchy? using an authorisation plugin such as [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) will allow me to define the different levels of authorisation, but not the relationships between the different users.

Essentially I would like a design that would enable me to write controller code such as this:

```
@level_two_users = current_user.find_all_my_level_two_users
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a attribute `level` to your user model and a method to query for allowed users.

To get all users with level X just use a query like `User.find_all_by_level(2)`

```
class User
  attr_accessible :level

  def allowed_to_edit_user?(user)
    case self[:level]
      when 1
        user.level > 1
      when 2
        user.level > 2 && user.created_by?(self)
    end
    false
  end

  def allowed_to_create_user_with_level?(level)
    self[:level] <= 2 && self[:level] < level 
  end
end
```

Btw. who creates level 1 users? ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the reply arnep, I am trying to run with your solution, and hit another hurdle, can you check my update above please?

Comment: @pingu You could use a `:has_many` relationship for the `creator` (one user has many other users as creator). Then you can use the `created_by?` method to query this relationship.